# Scraping wikipedia table to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, wikipedia

I need to scrape a wikipedia table to a pandas data frame and create three columns: PostalCode, Borough, and Neighborhoods.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M

Here is the code that I have used:

```
import requests
website_url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M').text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
My_table

links = My_table.findAll('a')
links

Neighbourhood = [ ]

for link in links:
    Neighbourhood.append(link.get('title'))

print (Neighbourhood)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([])
df['PostalCode', 'Borough', 'Neighborhood'] = Neighbourhood
df
```

And it returns that:

```
    (PostalCode, Borough, Neighborhood)
0   North York
1   Parkwoods
2   North York
3   Victoria Village
4   Downtown Toronto
5   Harbourfront (Toronto)
6   Downtown Toronto
7   Regent Park
8   North York
```

I can't figure out how to pick up the postcode and the neighbourhood from the wikipedia table.

Thank you

Comment: Please include the error message in your question. :)

Comment: Googlers should skip the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the error message. 
By looking at it, first you have df['Neighbourhoods'] = **Neighbourhoods** where your list has the name **Neighborhoods**.

Answer (score 11):

pandas allow you to do it in one line of code:

`df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two small errors:

`df = pd.dataframe()` should be `df = pd.DataFrame([])`

You also misspelled `Neighborhoods` as `Neighbourhoods` the second time.

You might also need to change `soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'xml')`, but we can't help you more without knowing your exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
df = pd.dataframe()
df['Neighbourhoods'] = Neighbourhoods
```

You can use

```
df['Neighbourhoods'] = pd.Series(Neighbourhoods)
```

This would solve your error and add new columns similarly using pd.Series(listname) or you can give list of lists containing PostalCode, Borough, and Neighborhoods using this code

```
df = pd.Dataframe(list_of_lists)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only picking up one of the columns here:

```
links = My_table.findAll('a')
```

You should be looking for `'tr'` rather than `'a'` as that signifies a new row in the table.

You should then use a for loop to populate a list of lists, this code should work:

```
v = []
 for tr in values:
   td = tr.find_all('td')
   row = [i.text for i in td]
   v.append(row)
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(v)
```